# Next.js / axios . Fetch data from mongo, data show up only in console.log

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios

I fetched data from mongo, I can see data in console.log() but I am not able to get data to screen. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?
How to fix it? Also console.log() show me data multiple times.

````
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
  const [teams, setTeams] = React.useState([])
 


  console.log(teams)

async function getData () {

  try {
   setLoading(true)

   await axios('/api/getTeam/data')
  .then(res => setTeams(res.data) )

    setLoading(false)

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    setLoading(false)
  }
}
  
useEffect(() => {
  getData()
},[])


```

console.log() 

```

[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]



```
````

Comment: Await it self will resolve the promise and yield the code execution until the task is finished. No need to use then if you are using await. Await will return the response capture that and then assign it.

Comment: Are you rendering the items of `teams` inside your component? Please add the whole file of your component so that we can help you more.